# Program doesn't read files from ZyBooks but works on Eclipse

Tags: java

**ZyBooks doesn't seem to want to run my program properly. What am I missing here? I'm using Eclipse as my IDE if it matters.**

```
public class Main {

    //method1 to print Welcome Message
    public static void printWelcomeMessage() {
        System.out.println("                 Program Number 1");
        System.out.println("                 Joe Blake");
        System.out.println("                 Computer Science 3");
    }

    //method2 to take input filename from user
    public static String InputFileName() {
        System.out.print("Enter file name:");
        //Input FileName from user and return
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

    //method 3 to find out Interest Rate
    public static double InterestRate(double yearOfDeposit) {
        //conditions
        if (yearOfDeposit >= 5)
            return 4.5;
        else if (yearOfDeposit >= 4)
            return 4;
        else if (yearOfDeposit >= 3)
            return 3.5;
        else if (yearOfDeposit >= 2)
            return 2.5;
        else if (yearOfDeposit >= 1)
            return 2;
        else
            return 1.5;
    }

    //method 4 to find number of times interest calculated
    public static int noOfTimeInterest(char code) {
        //conditions
        if (code == 'A' || code == 'a')
            return 4;
        else if (code == 'B' || code == 'b')
            return 2;
        else if (code == 'C' || code == 'c')
            return 1;
        else if (code == 'D' || code == 'd')
            return 12;
        else
            return 365;
    }

    //method 5 to calculate total earning
    public static double EarnedTotal(double p, double r, int n, double t) {
        double total_Interest = (p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / (100.0 * n))), (n * t))));
        return total_Interest;
    }

    //method 6 open file
    public static void openFile(String filename) {
        try {
            //create a file Object
            File myObj = new File(filename);
            //Scanner Object to read data from file
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            //if file is not empty
            if (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println("Name                 Years         Deposit Amount   Interest Earned  Total");
                //loop until file have data
                while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                    //read a line and store in name
                    String name = myReader.nextLine();
                    //read next line and store in data
                    String data = myReader.nextLine();
                    //split the string to fetch different values
                    String[] values = data.split(" ");
                    //fetch values
                    double Amount = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
                    double Deposited_Years = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
                    char code = values[2].charAt(0);
                    //calling method to find InterestRate
                    double rate = InterestRate(Deposited_Years);
                    //calling method noOfTimeInterest
                    int n = noOfTimeInterest(code);
                    //total Amount
                    double total = EarnedTotal(Amount, rate, n, Deposited_Years);
                    total = (double) Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
                    //calculating total_Interest by calling method InterestEarnedTotal
                    double total_Interest = total - Amount;
                    total_Interest = (double) Math.round(total_Interest * 100) / 100;
                    //print output and formatting
                    System.out.printf("%-20s %-10.0f %10s %15s %15s %n", name, Deposited_Years, "$" + Amount, "$" + total_Interest, "$" + total);
                }
                //print Message
                System.out.println("Thank you for using interest calculation program. Have a nice day");
                //close file
                myReader.close();
            } else {  // if file is empty
                System.out.println("There was no data in the file. Program terminated.");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  // if file not exists
            System.out.println("Could not open file. Program terminated.");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling printWelcomeMessage
        printWelcomeMessage();
        //calling InputFileName to take Input File name
        String filename = InputFileName();
        //openFile for calculation
        openFile(filename);
    }
}
```

**Expected output(for assign1CS3.txt), given by the ZyBooks automatic grader:**

```
Program Number 1
Joe Blake
Computer Science 3
Enter file name:
Name                Years  Deposit Amount   Interest Earned  Total
Joseph Kardian III  4.00   $1500.00         $258.87          $1758.87
Joe Karlton         4.00   $3000.00         $517.74          $3517.74
Nancy Brown         6.00   $6780.00         $2075.02         $8855.0
Mike Hrady          6.00   $6780.00         $2049.32         $8829.32
Albert Wilson       12.00  $12000.00        $8350.58         $20350.58
Mohadi Mudaber      4.00   $2340.00         $405.28          $2745.28
Joe Ban Kei         2.00   $1320.00         $67.46           $1387.46
Ali Mosaker         6.00   $15500.85        $4794.46         $20295.31
Kim Ji Yoo          10.00  $7890.90         $4484.15         $12375.05
Kelly Ma Tai        4.00   $3456.90         $599.77          $4056.67
Larry Brownsen Jr.  6.00   $78650.00        $24070.83        $102720.83
Joseph Wilson       4.00   $5500.00         $954.25          $6454.25
Ali Khan            4.00   $30000.00        $5177.36         $35177.36
Nancy Jones Brown   6.00   $67800.00        $20881.81        $88681.81
Mike Alisson        2.00   $61780.00        $3147.40         $64927.40
```

**Current output (in ZyBooks):**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
at main.openFile(main.java:85)
at main.main(main.java:129)
```

This is some filler text to meet the text-to-code ratio requirement. Learning Java so far has been pretty clunky in comparison to `C++`, especially when it comes to using ZyBooks.

Comment: You've got an empty string in your input file where you expect to read a double (Deposited_Years)

Comment: By the way, do you have those white-space slices (in the `println()`) purposefully? what for?